# Script for resizing is not working

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to resize my iframes height when the screen resizes. I have the following script inside my iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function sendHeight() {
            if (parent.postMessage) {
                // wrapper holds whole content of the page
                var height = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper").offsetHeight;
                parent.postMessage(height, '*');
            }
        }

        // Create browser compatible event handler.
        var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
        var eventer = window[eventMethod];
        var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

        // Listen for a message from the iframe.
        eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {

            if (isNaN(e.data)) return;

            sendHeight();

        },
        false);
    </script>
```

On the page, where I included my iframe I have:

```
<iframe id="iframeid" src="https://iframesource.com" scrolling="no" width="100%" onload="document.getElementById('load-img').style.display='none';"></iframe>

<script>

  // Create browser compatible event handler.
  var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
  var eventer = window[eventMethod];
  var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
  // Listen for a message from the iframe.
  eventer(messageEvent, function(e) {
    if (isNaN(e.data)) return;

    // replace #sizetracker with what ever what ever iframe id you need
    document.getElementById('antrag').style.height = e.data + 'px';

  }, false);
</script>
```

But it's not working. No errors are shown in the console.
My iframe is on a different domain.

How can I get this working? I have already searched for a solution but haven't found one...

Comment: well - your iframe already has 100% width - you can control that. or you can wrap your iframe in a div, that you control the size of, and control it that way, since it will be 100% of the wrappers width

Comment: `I want to resize my iframe when the screen resizes` in that case it would make far more sense to use CSS; either a `%` width or a responsive stylesheet.

Comment: The problem is the height of the content inside the iframe. If the content breaks in the iframe because the user has a smartphone for example, the iframe needs more height. If it doesn't get that, you can't see the content. Or if you give the iframe too much height, there is white space at the bottom of the page. I want to have a dynamic height

Comment: Since this has nothing to do with `jquery` I'm removing the tag.